# How to select each column from higher level column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select all population column from each country using pandas?

```
relationship_report.loc[:,('Angola':'Zimbabwe','population')]

relationship_report = pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([population_reports.columns,['population','co2','income']]),
                   index= population_reports.index)

relationship_report.loc[:,'Angola':'Zimbabwe']
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For questions like this, I generally use something like:

```
relationship_report.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'population']]
```

That should return all countries present along with their population in the second level of the multi-index.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your request

It is possible to perform quite complicated selections using the .slice() method on multiple axes at the same time. You can create an new multi-index DataFrame with your selection of 'population' doing something like this:

```
df = relationship_report.loc[:, (slice(None), 'population')]
```